# OSError: [Errno 24] Too many open files when using reactor.run() in Twisted

Tags: python, python-2.7, twisted, centos7

I am having a weird issue: I am running a large amount of `utils.getProcessOutputAndValue('cmd', [args])` commands and the result depends on whether I started the reactor using `task.react()` or `reactor.run()`

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from progress.bar import IncrementalBar
from twisted.internet import defer
from twisted.internet import task
from twisted.internet import utils
from twisted.python import usage


class Options(usage.Options):
    optFlags = [['reactor', 'r', 'Use reactor.run().'],
                ['task', 't', 'Use task.react().'],
                ['cwr', 'w', 'Use callWhenRunning().']]
    optParameters = [['limit', 'l', 255, 'Number of file descriptors to open.'],
                     ['cmd', 'c', 'echo Testing {i}...', 'Command to run.']]


def run(opt):
    limit = int(opt['limit'])
    cmd, args = opt['cmd'].split(' ', 1)
    bar = IncrementalBar('Running {cmd}'.format(cmd=opt['cmd']), max=limit)
    requests = []
    for i in range(0, limit):
        try:
            _args = args.format(i=i)
            args = _args
        except KeyError:
            pass
        requests.append(utils.getProcessOutputAndValue('echo', [args]))
        bar.next()
    bar.finish()
    return defer.gatherResults(requests)


@defer.inlineCallbacks
def main(reactor, opt):
    d = defer.Deferred()
    limit = int(opt['limit'])
    cmd, args = opt['cmd'].split(' ', 1)
    bar = IncrementalBar('Running {cmd}'.format(cmd=opt['cmd']), max=limit)
    for i in range(0, limit):
        try:
            _args = args.format(i=i)
            args = _args
        except KeyError:
            pass
        yield utils.getProcessOutputAndValue('echo', [args])
        bar.next()
    bar.finish()
    defer.returnValue(d.callback(True))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    opt = Options()
    opt.parseOptions()

    if opt['reactor']:
        from twisted.internet import reactor
        task.deferLater(reactor, 0, run, opt)
        reactor.run()

    elif opt['task']:
        from twisted.internet.task import react
        react(main, [opt])

    elif opt['cwr']:
        from twisted.internet import reactor
        reactor.callWhenRunning(run, opt)
        reactor.run()
```

When using `limit` above 400 (in my case) I get the following error:

```
Upon execvpe echo ['echo', 'Testing 0...'] in environment id 42131264
:Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/vagrant/.env/sm/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Twisted-15.5.0-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg/twisted/internet/process.py", line 428, in _fork
    self._setupChild(**kwargs)
  File "/home/vagrant/.env/sm/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Twisted-15.5.0-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg/twisted/internet/process.py", line 803, in _setupChild
    for fd in _listOpenFDs():
  File "/home/vagrant/.env/sm/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Twisted-15.5.0-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg/twisted/internet/process.py", line 638, in _listOpenFDs
    return detector._listOpenFDs()
  File "/home/vagrant/.env/sm/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Twisted-15.5.0-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg/twisted/internet/process.py", line 553, in _listOpenFDs
    self._listOpenFDs = self._getImplementation()
  File "/home/vagrant/.env/sm/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Twisted-15.5.0-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg/twisted/internet/process.py", line 576, in _getImplementation
    after = impl()
  File "/home/vagrant/.env/sm/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Twisted-15.5.0-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg/twisted/internet/process.py", line 606, in _procFDImplementation
    return [int(fd) for fd in self.listdir(dname)]
OSError: [Errno 24] Too many open files: '/proc/23421/fd'
Unhandled error in Deferred:
```

Which **does not occur** if I am using `task.react()`

In resume:

- `python pyerr.py -l100 -r`: **OK**
- `python pyerr.py -l100 -t`: **OK**
- `python pyerr.py -l100 -w`: **OK**
- `python pyerr.py -l400 -r`: **OSERR**
- `python pyerr.py -l400 -t`: **OK**
- `python pyerr.py -l400 -w`: **OSERR**

The problem is that I have a big application that uses reactor, because its an application responding to SMTP connections (so cannot use `task.react`, I do not want to stop the reactor).

I always thought that `task.react` was only stopping the reactor once the deferred is done, but I guess is doing more than this...

---

**edit**: Here a `pstree` comparaison for `task.react` vs `reactor.run`

**reactor.run (python pyerr.py -l400 -r)**:

```
init-+-VBoxService---7*[{VBoxService}]
     |-acpid
     |-atd
     |-cron
     |-dbus-daemon
     |-dhclient
     |-6*[getty]
     |-master-+-pickup
     |        `-qmgr
     |-mysqld---18*[{mysqld}]
     |-nginx---4*[nginx]
     |-php5-fpm---2*[php5-fpm]
     |-puppet---{puppet}
     |-rpc.idmapd
     |-rpc.statd
     |-rpcbind
     |-rsyslogd---3*[{rsyslogd}]
     |-ruby---{ruby}
     |-sshd-+-3*[sshd---sshd---sftp-server]
     |      |-sshd---sshd---2*[sftp-server]
     |      |-sshd---sshd---bash---pstree
     |      `-sshd---sshd---bash---python-+-323*[echo]
     |                                    `-5*[python]
     |-systemd-logind
     |-systemd-udevd
     |-upstart-file-br
     |-upstart-socket-
     `-upstart-udev-br
```

**task.react (python pyerr.py -l400 -t)**:

```
init-+-VBoxService---7*[{VBoxService}]
     |-acpid
     |-atd
     |-cron
     |-dbus-daemon
     |-dhclient
     |-6*[getty]
     |-master-+-pickup
     |        `-qmgr
     |-mysqld---18*[{mysqld}]
     |-nginx---4*[nginx]
     |-php5-fpm---2*[php5-fpm]
     |-puppet---{puppet}
     |-rpc.idmapd
     |-rpc.statd
     |-rpcbind
     |-rsyslogd---3*[{rsyslogd}]
     |-ruby---{ruby}
     |-sshd-+-3*[sshd---sshd---sftp-server]
     |      |-sshd---sshd---2*[sftp-server]
     |      |-sshd---sshd---bash---pstree
     |      `-sshd---sshd---bash---python---echo
     |-systemd-logind
     |-systemd-udevd
     |-upstart-file-br
     |-upstart-socket-
     `-upstart-udev-br
```

Notice the difference between this

```
 |      `-sshd---sshd---bash---python-+-323*[echo]
 |                                    `-5*[python]
```

and this

```
 |      `-sshd---sshd---bash---python---echo
```

in one cas it seems that processes are not closed as soon as completed.

I have tested this issue on 4 different machines:

- Ubuntu 14.04
- Centos 6
- Centos 7

The issue is exactly the same.

To give a shot, try run `watch -n 0.1 "pstree"` to see how the processes are evolving.

---

**edit: I get it why this is happening thanks to Glyph answer, but how to adapt this to my real life case ?**

The application I am developing with Twisted is an SMTP filter based on Milter, here how it works (assume we want to check the email signature):

- connection opens on port 25
- milter protocol get all emails details
- milter calls a remote "module" server that will handle the signature check with `/usr/bin/openssl mime` call
- the module will return an answer indicating whether or not the signature is valid

In this case, my problem is that is I get 150 simultaneous connections, there will be 150 calls to the module (TCP protocol) and this module will invoke the openssl command once per connection.

The module is completely agnostic, therefore will not know if other calls are running. Where should I put the `DeferredSemaphore` in your opinion ?

My problem here is that smtp connections are also agnostics and don't know about other possible opens connections.

What is the correct way of handling this parallellism in your opinion?

Comment: That *is* all `task.react` does.  Pasting your example onto a Linux server, I was able to run your example successfully for all the values you've provided, so I'm not sure what's going wrong.  Perhaps some local configuration issue?

Comment: I have ran the two examples with a `pstree` and when using the `-r` switch I saw 300 python subprocess, I will paste you a detailed sample in the morning. I have the impression that the processes hangs once terminated and cause the /proc limit error

Comment: I have added the `pstree` graph and detailed a bit my tests, this issue have been tested on 4 different machines with 3 different os. Note that I corrected the results: it is the **-r** switch `python pyerr.py -l400 -r` that fails, not the **-t**

Comment: I'm able to reproduce your failure mode now; I am not sure what I did wrong before.

Comment: And now I can see what the problem is - I'll go ahead and write an answer :).  Sorry for my incorrect diagnosis!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem here has nothing to do with the distinction between `task.react` and `reactor.run`, but rather, the subtle but significant difference between the implementation of your `run` and `main` functions.

The difference is that `run` is spawning `limit` processes *in parallel*, racking up thousands of simultaneous open file descriptors, easily blowing through your system's limitations.  However, `main` is waiting for every process to completely finish executing before even starting up the next one, which means it never uses more than 4 or 5 at a time.

The reason is that `main` is decorated by `inlineCallbacks` and yields every `getProcessOutputAndValue` `Deferred`, which suspends execution of `main` until that `Deferred` has completed.

In real applications, neither of these approaches is ideal.  You want some parallelism, but not unlimited.  Twisted comes with some utilities, such as [`DeferredSemaphore`](https://twistedmatrix.com/documents/16.0.0/api/twisted.internet.defer.DeferredSemaphore.html), to facilitate limited parallelism without restricting everything to only run one task at a time.  Jean-Paul Calderone wrote an article - 10 years ago! - that explains how to use this, [here](http://as.ynchrono.us/2006/05/limiting-parallelism_22.html).

However, just to demonstrate that the issue has nothing to do with `task.react`, here's a modified version of your example which eliminates the `run` function and makes an apples-to-apples comparison using `main`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from progress.bar import IncrementalBar
from twisted.internet import defer
from twisted.internet import task
from twisted.internet import utils
from twisted.python import usage


class Options(usage.Options):
    optFlags = [['reactor', 'r', 'Use reactor.run().'],
                ['task', 't', 'Use task.react().'],
                ['cwr', 'w', 'Use callWhenRunning().']]
    optParameters = [['limit', 'l', 255, 'Number of file descriptors to open.'],
                     ['cmd', 'c', 'echo Testing {i}...', 'Command to run.']]


@defer.inlineCallbacks
def main(reactor, opt):
    d = defer.Deferred()
    limit = int(opt['limit'])
    cmd, args = opt['cmd'].split(' ', 1)
    bar = IncrementalBar('Running {cmd}'.format(cmd=opt['cmd']), max=limit)
    for i in range(0, limit):
        try:
            _args = args.format(i=i)
            args = _args
        except KeyError:
            pass
        yield utils.getProcessOutputAndValue('echo', [args])
        bar.next()
    bar.finish()
    defer.returnValue(d.callback(True))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    opt = Options()
    opt.parseOptions()

    if opt['reactor']:
        from twisted.internet import reactor
        task.deferLater(reactor, 0, main, reactor, opt)
        reactor.run()

    elif opt['task']:
        from twisted.internet.task import react
        react(main, [opt])

    elif opt['cwr']:
        from twisted.internet import reactor
        reactor.callWhenRunning(main, reactor, opt)
        reactor.run()
```

**edit, responding to edit in the question:**

Since your *real* problem is with incoming connections, and not just a `for` loop, rather than using `DeferredSemaphore`, you might instead need to maintain a counter, and take advantage of the fact that the object returned from [`listenTCP`](https://twistedmatrix.com/documents/16.0.0/api/twisted.internet.interfaces.IReactorTCP.html#listenTCP), or the result of the `Deferred` that comes back from [`TCP4ServerEndpoint`](https://twistedmatrix.com/documents/16.0.0/api/twisted.internet.endpoints.TCP4ServerEndpoint.html), implements [`IPushProducer`](https://twistedmatrix.com/documents/16.0.0/api/twisted.internet.interfaces.IPushProducer.html), and call `pauseProducing()` on it when too many concurrent connections are doing work, and `resumeProducing()` when that work is done.

Comment: Thank you, I totally get it now, the more I dig, the more I love Twisted ;) . Could you please check my last edit to see how I should proceed in my real case ?

Comment: Do you know where I can find a full example of consumer/producer implementation?

Comment: https://github.com/notoriousno/ftpclient/blob/master/ftpclient.py#L131. Please note this is not a very good example and it was written when I knew very little about Twisted :D. Basically, once a ``protocol.transport`` is available, register transports as producers, then pause, resume, and unregister as needed.  http://twistedmatrix.com/documents/current/core/howto/producers.html